# Observe property and run code after View is inDOM

Tags: ember.js

I'm observing a property on my view to draw charts.
The problem: the observer triggers before the view is `inDOM`.

Is there a way to wait until the state changes?

```
App.ReportsView = Ember.View.extend({

  drawChart: function() {

    console.log(this.get('state'));
    // draw some charts

  }.observes('controller.chartData.projects')

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View has a **state** property where you can check if it is in DOM, but it is not a public API.

You could set a property in your view when it has been inserted in DOM by listening the **didInsertElement** event.

This could be a possible approach (not tested):

```
App.ReportsView = Ember.View.extend({

  setInDOM: function(){

    this.set('isInDom', true);
    this.drawChart();

  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  tryDrawChart: function() {

    if ( this.get('isInDom') ) {
      this.drawChart();
    } 

  }.observes('controller.chartData.projects'),

  drawChart: function() {

  }

});
```

Comment: But, the observer triggers only once, or? That means: if `chartData.projects` changes, than `if ( this.get('isInDom') ) {` can't get true, because the data changes faster then the DOM? Or does the observer triggers multiple times when the state changes too?

Comment: I updated the response to include drawChart in the didInsertElement, so you ensure that the chart if draw when the view is inserted in DOM.